# Table disappears after adding an item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

i'm using datatables to display a list of project names and I'm using a button to add an item to the displayed array, but when i do so, my table disappears.

Here's the code:

view.html

```
<button ng-click="vm.add()">Add item</button>
<table datatable="ng" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs"
       class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #00b3ee; color: white; border:none">
        <th style="text-align: center">Nom</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="project in vm.project.projects">
        <td style="width: 90%; vertical-align: middle">{{project}}</td>
        <td align="center" style="vertical-align: middle">
            <button data-toggle="modal" ng-click="vm.setProject(project)"
                    data-target="#deleteEureciaProjectModal" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Supprimer
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

controller.js

```
vm.add = () => vm.project.projects.push('new project');

fetchProject().then(result => {
    vm.project = result;

    // vm.project = {
    //     projects: [
    //         "project1",
    //         "project2",
    //         "project3",
    //         "project4"
    //     ],
    //     etc...
    // }

    vm.project.projects.push("newProject"); //it's working here, which is normal

    //init datatable
    vm.dtInstance = {};
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withBootstrap();
    vm.dtColumnDefs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            vm.dtColumnDefs.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i).notSortable());
        } else {
            vm.dtColumnDefs.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i));
        }
    }
})
```

I've tried using objects instead of strings.. doesn't work either. I don't know what's going on.
I cannot use server side processing. This has to be done using the angular way.

Comment: With a minimal example, I can't replicate your problem. Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QsWub9q2FS5i6kLdbXWP?p=preview)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I am using angular-datatables, your plunker is assuming I am using basic angular.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found it :

For some reason, it worked when i initialized `vm.project.project` before the promise call. So i created the `vm.project` object, and i added the `project` property to it by adding an empty array. I was then able to add items without having my table disappearing.